# React Router not loading new page. No errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My React Redux Router works like this in my project
*index.js*

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

store.dispatch(getAllMenu());

render((
    <Provider store={store}>
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Menu />
   </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>),

  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

*Routes.js*

```
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
        <Route path='/subMenu' component={subMenu}/>
        <Route path='/Dummy' component={Dummy}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Main;
```

*Menu.js*

```
const Menu = () => (
  <div>
    <HeaderContainer />
    <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>Menu</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/subMenu'>subMenu</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/Dummy'>Dummy</Link></li>
    </ul>
    <section className="content menuCategoryPage">
      <h1 className="pageTitle">Bob Evans Menu</h1>
      <hr/>
      <ProductsContainer />
    </section>
  </div>
)

export default Menu
```

*Dummy.js*

```
const Dummy = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>This is a dummy page!</h2>
  </div>
)


export default Dummy;
```

There are no errors and links appear on the home mage(Menu.js) but when I try to go to Dummy Page, it shows the home page again. What am I doing wrong?
Is  in my index.js causing all this?

Comment: You should specify what version of React Router you are using.

Comment: I don't see `Main` used anywhere

Comment: I am using "react-router": "^4.1.1",

Comment: I figured out my issue. I had to redefinbe Main.js as import React from 'react';  
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';  
import Menu from './containers/Menu';  
import subMenu from './containers/subMenu/subMenu'; 
import Dummy from './containers/Dummy'; 

class Main extends React.Component {
 render() {
     return (
     <main>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
         <Route path='/subMenu' component={subMenu}/>
         <Route path='/Dummy' component={Dummy}/>
       </Switch>
     </main>
   );
  }
 }

export default Main;